# SKR Mini E3 V2 - PWM on PC12 possible?

Tags: marlin, firmware, skr-mini-e3

The SKR Mini E3 V2 uses the STM32F103RCF6 MCU based around ARM.

I want to control the pin `PC12` with PWM. However, this pin is not working as the Laser PWM signal. It never gets triggered actually with `G0`/`G1 S0-255`, although I am absolutely sure, that this is not an issue with the laser configuration itself. When manually setting the pin state with G-code I can only set it to 0 V with `S0` or to 3.3V with `S1` to S255. It is not doing any kind of PWM at all. The same can be observed with `PC6` vs `PC7`. `PC6` is the parts cooling fan and it outputs PWM signals. `PC7` is the controller fan and it does not output PWM. I have checked the 2 main Configs of Marlin and the Pins BTT... and BTT...common for any clues, however regarding the definition of these pins I see no difference.

After looking up the pins using the PDF of the manufacturer, I cannot see a difference between `PC6` and `PC7` - both are paper-wise supporting the same features and just have a different index - which is kind of obvious. So how is it possible, that one pin can be set to PWM states, while the other pins (without exception) only react digitally with a `0` or `1` state?

Please do not consider the version, which is 2.0.9.1, quite outdated. I have to stick to the version for like a dozen of reasons. It is a fork anyways, so what gives? I do not actually want to ask about firmware version things, but how it is possible, that there is a difference on this level at all? If I set the pin state whilst disabling firmware protection of this pin I would expect the pin to react as PWM, if I ask it to. I mean, using the thermistor pins as output is possible, which works as expected. From the chip datasheet and the configuration files I cannot see a reason, why the pins would behave differently. The circuit between `PC6` and `PC7` is absolutely identical, so this is out of the question already.

Is there any function, that needs to be called or a setting that needs to be made for PWM to be even loaded/initialized at all? I see many people struggling to set PWM to any pin other than the parts cooling fan, so it is not a new issue. I never saw a real fix for this, only suggestions like Buck converter for manual adjustments.

I want to control a laser, so this is out of the question. Any idea?